# problem during inserting data with libpq in c

Tags: c, postgresql

I have a code which read data from some files and then try to add those data line by line to database. The problem is when I run the program it just add the first line of data into database and then it occurs `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

```c
void add_line_to_db(char *line, PGconn *connection, PGresult *re){

    char query[50];
    split(line);

    sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO fp_stores_data_test "\
                    "VALUES (%s,'%s','%s',%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
                    ,splitted_line[0],splitted_line[1]
                    ,splitted_line[2],splitted_line[3]
                    ,splitted_line[4],splitted_line[5]
                    ,splitted_line[6],splitted_line[7]);

    re = PQexec(connection,query);

    if(PQresultStatus(re) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK){
        printf("%s\n", PQresultErrorMessage(re));
    }

    PQclear(re);
}



void read_file_line_by_line(char *filename, char *address, PGconn *connection, PGresult *re){

    char file_address[50];
    strcpy(file_address, address);
    strcat(file_address, filename);
    FILE *file = fopen(file_address, "r");
    char line[256];

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)){

        add_line_to_db(line, connection, re);   
        printf("this line!\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
}



int main(){

    //char address = "/tmp/final_project/";
    PGconn *con;
    PGresult *res;
    con = make_connection();
    
    //make_connection(con);
    create_table_fp_stores_data(res, con);

    char file_name[20];
    list_dir_files("/tmp/final_project/");  
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_files; i++){

        strcpy(file_name, dir_content[i]);
        read_file_line_by_line(file_name, "/tmp/final_project/", con, res);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `splitted_data` array is a 2-d global char array which will change for every loop. although the function `add_line_to_db` will complete for the first loop but `printf("line line\n");` after that does't run.
I'm trying to avoid congestion and then I don't want to put my whole code here, but on the other hand I don't know where exactly problem is so I can't put the specific lines here.

Comment: Never use user-input directly as values in embedded SQL code, it's a recipe for disaster (learn the tale of [little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)). Please do some research about prepared statements and variable placeholders.

Comment: And please don't use global variables to "return" values from functions. The fewer global variables you have the better.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Excuse me, I don't understand what's your meaning of 'user-input'. would you explain more?

Comment: And does the whole query with all strings really fit in a 50-character string? That seems very small.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're right, length of array was less than query size, I fixed it but still occurs `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Try to step through the code with the debugger. You will see exactly where the problem happens.

Comment: Use a debugger to catch the crash as it happens, then locate where in your code it happens, and check the values of all involved variables at that point (including checking the lengths of strings).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I read data from a file using `fgets`. Is this possible that it miss a char like `\r` or `\n` and this makes problem?

Comment: OT: you probably do not want to put the trailing '\n' into the data base.  Therefore, the first line after the call to `fgets()` could be: `line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`  which, if there is a trailing '\n', overlays it with '\0' and, otherwise this statement has no effect on `line[]`

Comment: There is no `split()` function in C, is this a function you wrote?  If so, then please post that function.

Comment: @user3629249 that's my own function.